# Ensure floats are placed before some section, subsections, subsubsections

Tags: floats

I'm writing a description of few hiking paths, grouped all in the same section, but in different subsection and subsubsection.

Attached to description there are few tables and figures in floats, and I would like floats are placed "not too after" the start of a new path description. With something like this:

```
3. Hiking Path Descriptions
3.1 Path 1

\FloatBarrier
3.2 Path 2 family
3.2.1 Path 2.1 

\FloatBarrier
3.2.2. Path 2.2 

\FloatBarrier
3.2.3 Path 2.3

\FloatBarrier
3.3 Path 3 family
3.3.1 Path 3.1 

\FloatBarrier
3.3.2 Path 3.2

\FloatBarrier
4 What to put in the backpack
```

I can ensure floats are placed before a new path description begins, but this is a big constraint, and I end up with part of few pages page left blank.

I can accept that, for example, figures of path 1 goes few lines after section 3.2.1 start, but not that many figures of path 1 goes one or more full pages after section 3.2.1 start.

Seems `\afterpage{\clearpage}` would be exactly what I need to replace my `\FloatBarrier`, but this cause (in my big document, not in any MWE I tried) the "float losts" error.

Any other option?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are doing, or trying to do. Among other things in your question what is the "marked line"?

Comment: It is very hard to understand your question as there is no example shown but as far as I can tell `\FloatBarrier` is what you want and `\afterpage{\clearpage}` won't help at all (it will still allow floats to float out of a section)

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I tried to better explain.